# tf.placeholder_with_default backprop

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am trying to train an autoencoder in Tensorflow.  However, this autoencoder is only one part of my architecture.  I would like to have the following workflow:

Input image-->Data processed upstream-->Fed into Autoencoder-->Encoded image output and its gradients are used.

In other words, I would like to have gradients of the entire encoding operation, including the upstream data processing, w.r.t the Input image data.

I would also like to train my autoencoder, by itself.  Therefore, I thought I could make the input images to the autoencoder of type `tf.placeholder_with_default`.  The idea would be that I could connect the upstream data processing directly into the autoencoder input to be the default, but alternatively allow users to pass in training data for training.

Therefore, I construct inputs to the autoencoder as such:

```
input_x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 60, 200, 3])) #Will be fed in from upstream, for now, zeros is just for testing
self.x = tf.placeholder_with_default(input_x, shape=[None, 60, 200, 3], name='camera') #images are 200 x 60 with 3 channels; x is the input to the autoencoder
```

My autoencoder involves several invocations of `tf.nn.conv2d`. Unfortunately, when I try to train using this setup, I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Conv2DSlowBackpropInput: input and out_backprop must have the same batch sizeinput batch: 1outbackprop batch: 32 batch_dim: 0
```

When I change my code to:

```
self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 60, 200, 3], name='camera')
```

I have no problems.

Am I trying to use `tf.placeholder_with_default` correctly?  What might cause the error?  (I can provide more code but would prefer not to post my entire AE if possible).

Comment: Can you try replacing your input_x declaration to :  `input_x =np.zeros([1, 60, 200, 3], dtype=np.float32)` ?

Comment: That runs...but...why?  a) That directly contradicts the TF documentation, which says the input should be a tensor: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder_with_default and b) does not solve the problem of being able to switch between a symbolic or numerical default.

Comment: Well, I don't have a very smart sounding answer - but from my experience, when I'm having difficulty with tf object datatypes, I usually just swap it out with a near equivalent from numpy and it solves my problem. I'm glad this solution worked for you! @user650261

Comment: I updated the answer. Would you be able to accept it, in case it is helpful for someone else?

Comment: It doesn't work for me.  It runs, but this doesn't solve my core problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your input_x declaration to :

```
input_x =np.zeros([1, 60, 200, 3], dtype=np.float32)
```